# Magento error when calling /rest/all/schema?services=all

Tags: error, api, interface

When calling http://b2b.localhost/rest/all/schema?services=all on local server I get error:

```
<response>
<message>The "OrderItemInterface[]" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again.</message>
<trace>#0 /var/www/html/b2b/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(103):...
```

I have a second magento on localhost and I am getting json correctly. What could be the problem?